# How do I restrict input when the number of entries for a condition is met?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

I am using a Google spreadsheet to gather the Registration form entries for our tournament. We can only have ten teams per age group.

How do I "close" the Registration when the number of entries for that age group reaches 10?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a conditional column and sheet.

Pros: quick and dirty.

Cons: you need to keep watching out if check changes fro FREE to FULL (added a conditional markup when it hits FULL ==> colored red). Logic needs tobe copied accordingly.

See example I've prepared: [conditional column/sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGJ3X2JXYzFlOVRUR2Y3Y0Z0ZlpIRlE)

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to prevent data entry conditionally is to apply Data validation (under the Data menu item). For simplicity, in an example I have restricted to three entries per group (rather than your ten) and for illustration chose "Show warning" rather than "Reject input":

[image: WA35286 first example]

A fourth entry for `Group C` has triggered the red triangles. Clear A10, switch to "Reject input" and an attempt to enter `C` there will be blocked.

The validation rule (adjusted for your 10) is:

```
=countif(A:A,A1)<11
```

[image: WA35286 second example]

Not that the validation is on the number of instances in ColumnA (age groups) - the number of names in ColumnB are not directly involved (so two or more names of different people in a single cell,or duplicate entries, and this approach would not work). Also, if your age groups are named say `10-15`, `16-18` etc care would be needed with consistency as `10 - 15` and `16+` for example would be treated as separate groups, from the former pair.